# Need to get drives of a user site which is hosted within a enterprise sharepoint online root site

Tags: sharepoint, office365, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

We have integrated Microsoft Graph Api's for Sharepoint Online.
If our drive is in the root site it works fine.
But for enterprise site
E.g
enterprise site: https://organisation.sharepoint.com
user site within it: xyz
complete URL: **https://organisation.sharepoint.com/sites/xyz**

I have a document library **DL** withing this user site. How can I get the Drive-Id of this document library using graph api?

I am only getting site id for https://organisation.sharepoint.com
and drives within this

Comment: Could you describe your problem in more detail? As my understand, do you have get the site id, and you want to get the drive in it?

Comment: I can access the drive id from the root site like https://organisation.sharepoint.com  but in an enterprise the root site is not accessible. Users create their own site within the root site. E.g user xyz has a site https://organisation.sharepoint.com/sites/xyz . Within this he has a document library named 'DL'. Queries 1. How to get the user site id from the root site using graph api 2. how to get user drive id from root site using graph api

Comment: It can be done using https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/organisation.sharepoint.com/sites?search=*. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I presume you want to get the drive in a site.

Based on my test, you can use the following APIs:

`GET /sites/{siteId}/drive`

The `siteId` parameter can be `xyz` base on your posted. It will return the default document library in this site.

For more detail, we can check [this document](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/drive_get#get-the-document-library-for-a-site).